# Linux i7 Rig for quiet stability and maybe a little Quake Live

Tags: linux, intel-core-i7, nehalem

I am considering [building a PC](http://natalian.org/archives/2009/08/21/Building_a_PC/) for the first time in about 10 years. I would really appreciate a review of the components I have chosen. I hope to run mainly [ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/), where I'll be doing browser development (WebKit builds) and [Debian Live](http://debian-live.alioth.debian.org/) builds. Though from time to time, I would like to frag in [Quake Live](http://www.quakelive.com/). :)

## Component list (Budget ~800GBP)

### Case

I've been told I need at least 500W. I wonder can I get a PSU with a display that shows how much power my rig is sucking down?

- [Antex 300](http://www.dabs.com/products/antec-three-hundred-case-black-6252.html) ~45GBP (needs a PSU)

or

- [Antec NSK 6580B](http://www.ebuyer.com/product/145090) ~80GBP

### Hard drive

- [160GBP 10000RPM VelociRaptor](http://www.dabs.com/products/western-digital-150gb-velociraptor-10-000rpm-sata-16mb-56WH.html) - 111GBP

or

- [80GB Intel SSD](http://www.scan.co.uk/product.aspx?ProductId=27605) ~200GBP

## i7

Does this box come with a stock cooler?

- [Intel's Nehalem 920  CPU](http://www.dabs.com/products/intel-nehalem-i7-920-s1366-2-66ghz-5CC9.html) ~200GBP

## Mainboard

Intel is most likely to be stable and have good BIOS upgrades that work in Linux. Right?

- [Intel DX58SO](http://www.dabs.com/products/intel-s1366-intel-x58-atx-audio-lan-5JQ9.html) ~188GBP

## Video card

I need (at least) two DVI outputs for two monitors with Xinerama

- [GeForce GTS 250 Dual DVI](http://www.dabs.com/products/bfg-graphics-geforce-gts-250-750mhz-1gb-pci-express-2-0-dual-dvi-5K1T.html?refs=42740000) ~130GBP

or

- [GeForce 9600GT Dual DVI](http://www.dabs.com/products/xfx-geforce-9600gt-650mhz-512mb-ddr3-pcie-dvi-5DDW.html?q=9600gT%20dual) ~60GBP

## RAM

- [4G of DDR3 RAM](http://www.dabs.com/products/corsair-memory-4gb--2x2gb-kit--ddr3-1600mhz-240pin-unbuffered-50TW.html#reviews) ~65GBP

Comment: I really don't think the reference to Quake Live is necessary in this question. It does however stand on it's own without.

Comment: You can get a killawatt http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/travelpower/7657/ which will tell you what all sorts of things are using powerwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going a little overkill here.  For quake live you won't need more than an 7800 series nvidia card, and I know my 9600GT happily runs dual monitors (with compiz) and any modern games.  Hell I had a Windows 7 partition for a while and the 9600 ran the Crysis demo with ~high settings at 1680x1050 at >20fps.  I say step down a notch or two on the video card, you aren't really going to need the extra power and you can put that money into a second, larger hard drive for storing all your files that don't require the R/W speeds of a 10k rpm or solid state drive (music, movies, etc).

Comment: I agree. Maybe I'll get one of these. http://www.dabs.com/products/seagate-barracuda-1tb-7200rpm-32mb-sata-300-5G7R.html